# use of unassigned local variable c#

Tags: c#

i have declared a variable in the beginning of program. i believe the variable is declared and used within the scope of the program.

```
double a,u; int i;
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    u += (i + 1) * datas[i];
}
```

i can check the value of u stored via debugging mode but could not use it elsewhere "use of unassigned local variable u" should i use decimal instead? i trued using decimal but since i also used

```
datas[i-1] = Convert.ToDouble(dataReader["high"]);
```

somewhere else in the program i dont think there is Convert.toDecimal() available in c#; what is the difference between double and decimal. PS: I have never used decimal before

Comment: The first time that the program runs `u += X`, it should add `X` to what? The compiler tells you that if you want `u` to start as zero you should be explicit.

Comment: -1, poor research. Variants of this question are abundant on the internet and here. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=use+of+unassigned+local+variable

Comment: You should really make an effort to google these kinds of things first.

Comment: @tnw: The question clearly shows that the OP invested time into not only trying to understand what's happening (*...via debugging mode...*) but also into writing something better than the usual type of "give me teh codes" junk that you see here often. I for one do not believe that not understanding what's going on was for lack of trying. And I certainly don't want to drive away people who may not know much but do show willingness to learn.

Comment: You can't user += operator on "u" for its very first operation because it has not been assigned. try setting u = 0 at declaration

Comment: @Jon OK? And? I never said there was no effort put into the question, but basic diagnostic steps weren't taken. Are you saying that OP shouldn't bother to Google things before posting questions?

Comment: @tnw that is not fair to the OP. They did not understand the problem, and therefore had no idea where to start. I think you should learn some manners and stop being so hostile

Comment: It's not fair to suggest someone google a problem first? Wat.

Comment: @tnw, no, it's not fair to accuse someone of "not bothering" to google

Comment: @imulson, a good place to start would be typing the exact question title into google/stackoverflow search and reading. Just *look* at the search results, *look* at the related questions to the side. Do we need yet another one? This website is getting pathetic, far too tolerant of nonsense, repetitive questions. This isn't a forum, this is a Q & A database, and this question and answer already exists. Let's stop spoon-feeding, and stop repeating ourselves.

Comment: Well , when i first asked question , i was going down and down vote , Did not liked it and even abdonded asking question on stack overflow.com

Comment: @faheemkhan one of the major problems with this site is hostility to new users who have not got used to asking questions well yet

Comment: @imulsion aaaaand that's why I suggest people use GOOGLE before asking questions. I have no idea how you're arguing against that.

Comment: @tnw: My comment was not aiming to change your personal opinion, which is not unreasonable (it would not be aiming to do that even if I did find it unreasonable). It was aiming to provide a counter-argument and hopefully stop the cascade of herd downvotes that would have left another new user thinking that SO is populated exclusively by jerks.

Comment: @Jon well said. i remember still the horror of being a new user

Comment: @Jon, this site is not and never will be about users, and if we scare people off from asking questions that already exist, then **good**.

Comment: @Jon Apparently you don't want to suggest that people Google things just because you feel bad. Sorry, I don't, because that just leads to low-quality duplicates like this that can be easily solved by doing about 30 seconds of research on your own. I'm honestly baffled as to how you guys can possibly encourage this kind of stuff.

Comment: @user414076 im sure this site will do very well without users

Comment: @imulsion Yeah, I don't think  this site is in any danger of failing because someone took it personally when they were told to just google their question.

Comment: @user414076: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize this site was yours to do with as you personally please.

Comment: @tnw: Then spend more time trying to understand where we are coming from and less time on pointless disagreements. I 'm very much pro-googling and pro-RTFMing. It's just that when someone has already given me adequate proof that they don't just want someone to do their homework for them, I 'm not so quick to *assume* what they did or did not do. People have different approaches to unlocking mysteries and varying degrees of proficiency at googling etc.

Comment: Also, people... despite the generous amounts of time spent on commenting, I do not see even **one** closevote pointing to a good duplicate. You would think that since we all have the best interests of SO in mind someone would have thought of that by now.

Comment: I never asked anyone to write code for me; i tried a bit but could not find it. I did not know that and I am not ashamed of it. answer of use "u=0" or "assign u with a value" would be so helpful. Anyway thank you for the help. It was helpful

Comment: @user414076 that's an absurd thing to say.  **Obviously** SO is about users.  What new users sometimes don't understand is that it's not about them getting an answer to their question, it's about collecting questions and answers to those question in a way that maximizes their usefulness to _all_ users.  Most of the time, that path goes right through the stopping point of them getting an answer to their questions, but not always.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C#, the use of uninitialized variables is not allowed. If you do not assign a default value, or use a constructor, the compiler won't know what your value is and therefore cannot use it.

You need to change `double a` for `double a = 0;` or `double a = new double();`. The `new double()` operation will set the default value to zero, according to this [default value table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/83fhsxwc.aspx). However, `= 0` is the preferred syntax.

As a side note, declaring variables on their own line is also a good practice in C#. So is declaring the loop variable directly in the `for` statement. I'd also recommend using meaningful variable names (`a` and `u` are not obvious for everyone), readability is pretty important.

```
double a = 0;
double u = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    u += (i + 1) * datas[i];
}
```

---

> what is the difference between double and decimal.

[`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) is usually used for currency or financial operations because of its greater precision (28-29 digits, compared to 15-16 for double). However, it have a much *much* smaller range than double. `decimal` range goes up to 7.9 x 10^28, while [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) goes up to 1.7 x 10^308.

On the other hand, if you don't need great precision or great range, [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) would be the best type to use as it is 32-bit (compared to 64 for double).

Comment: +1 for in depth answer and getting into good practices

Comment: Another good practice would be eliminting `30`

Answer (score 9):

The variable u has not been assigned a value, and therefore can't be used in a loop. Try this instead:

```
double a = 0;double u = 0; int i;
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
    u += (i + 1) * datas[i];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The variable `u` is not assigned in the first execution of `u += ...`
and since `u += x;` is equivalent to `u = u + x;` it follows that the compiler will flag this. `u` does have a default value of `0` but the compiler will not let you use that, it enforces good programming style here.

What you probably want is:

```
double a, u = 0; 

for (int i = 0; i < datas.Length; i++)
{
    u += (i + 1) * datas[i];
}
```

You could still run into the same problem for `a` though.

Comment: This is a rubbish answer. Why do so many people auto upvote users with such high rep?

Comment: What is the rubbish part?

Comment: The useless bit of text you put just so you could be first on the board. No help on it's own... it only becomes useful when you edit more in

Comment: i got some problem so i asked. @HenkHolterman isnt stackoverflow for beginners?

Comment: @KageRai it's not exclusively for beginners. IMO, this is an OK question, but many won't agree with me

Comment: @KageRai - the criticism here is not aimed at you. And yes SO is for beginners but we do expect some effort in the question. Yours looks OK.

Comment: @musefan - I messed up declared and assigned for a second but basically the first sentence addresses the core problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign a value to `u` before you will use it.

```
double u = 0;
```

Compiler converts `u += 1` to `u = u + 1`. As you can see, you read `u`, but haven't assigned a value to this variable. That's why compiler tells that you are using unassigned local variable

Answer (score 0):

You have never assigned a value to the variable u. change your declaration to...

double u = 0;

Comment: What I should have said was 'you never assigned a value to u' , hence the error "use of unassigned local variable".

Comment: why not edit your question rather than leave a comment? :)